# Displaying the name of the line on the plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

With the help of this code, I displayed several lines on one field

```
for platform in ['PS2', 'X360', 'PS3', 'Wii', 'DS', 'PS']:
    df = df_sales_year.query('platform == @platform')
    x = df['year_of_release']
    y = df['total_sales']
    ax.plot(x, y, label=platform) 
plt.title('Количество продаж в год на платформах', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Год', fontsize=14)   
plt.ylabel('Продажи(млн. копий)', fontsize=14);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please tell me how you can sign each line. Tried with label, doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `plt.legend()`?

Comment: Perfect, happy coding ;)